# Ctrl-Z clears text area content in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, textarea

```
<textarea name="" cols="" rows="" id=updateGroupDescription></textarea>
```

The above textarea is opened in div popup.
click on text area.

Do ctrl-z clears the content of textarea in IE.

But this will not happen in other browsers.
Even though the ctrl-z functionality seems to working fine in all the browsers,
IE clears the content even before editing.

Any suggestion on this will be very helpful..
thanks

Comment: You need to add quotes around updateGroupDescription.

Comment: Please provide more information (sample code or URL, IE version, etc.). The issue cannot be reconstructed in a simple setting. Ctrl Z acts as undo in some environments; when the last operation was typing in text, undo removes the typed text. I cannot find any difference here between IE and other browsers.